# gdaldem hillshade using command to calculate hillshade of whole folder

Tags: gdal, dem, hillshade, gdaldem

I need to calculate hillshade of folder using gdaldem hillshade which has 60 files in it. How can i do it using command prompt window.

Answer (score 3):

first solution is to create a FOR loop in DOS, but this is a bit out of scope.

second solution is to build a vrt (make a virtual mosaic in your case) with all files and run gdaldem on it

```
gdalbuilvrt mosaic.vrt path_to_your_images/*.tif
gdaldem hillshade mosaic.vrt output_hillshade.tif
```

Comment: how can i save hillshaded files with another name.

Comment: the vrt is a mosaic, then you have a single file.

Comment: i don't understand. Can you provide me the full details with code plz

Comment: i am beginner to it.

Comment: vrt will virtually stitch the files together in a single large file. You just need to replace the input and output paths in my edited post.